# How can i stop the groupMonitor.run method from crashing my ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java

groupMonitor.run("", "") is listening via IP Network to some electrical components.

- The problem: is that all 5-6 hours groupMonitor.run("", "") crashes and needs to be called again. Quickly said: groupMonitor.run("", "") has to listen all the time via IP Network.
- Another problem is: when groupMonitor.run("", "") crashes it prints all 100ms "redo groupMonitor ..." and is spaming my network so heavily that my IP Gateway (which accepts the connections) gets stuck and refuses all future incoming requests

**This is the minimied main so to say**

```
        GroupMonitorOrig groupMonitor = new GroupMonitorOrig();
//when new groupMonitor is created the boolean MonitorExited is initialized with true


        while (true) {
            if (groupMonitor.monitorExited) { //this part gets executed when groupMonitor.run("", "") method has "crashed"
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("redo groupMonitor ... ");
                            groupMonitor.run("192.168.1.7", 2169);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                    }
                };

                ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

**This is groupmonitor's run function**

```
    public void run(String remoteHost, int port) {
        final InetSocketAddress remote = new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, port);
        
        try (KNXNetworkLink knxLink = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(null, remote, false, TPSettings.TP1);
                ProcessCommunicator pc = new ProcessCommunicatorImpl(knxLink)) {

            // start listening to group notifications using a process listener
            pc.addProcessListener(this);
            System.out.println("Monitoring network using net/IP server " + remoteHost + " ...");

            while (knxLink.isOpen()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            monitorExited = false;
            pc.detach();
        } catch (final KNXException | InterruptedException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            monitorExited = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test run but can you try below -

The `while(true)` can be avoided

---

```
   GroupMonitorOrig groupMonitor = new GroupMonitorOrig();
    //when new groupMonitor is created the boolean MonitorExited is initialized with true

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
               if (groupMonitor.monitorExited) {
                   System.out.println("starting new groupMonitor ... ");
                   groupMonitor.run("192.168.1.7", 2169);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("Error in Runnable - " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

---

```
public void run(String remoteHost, int port) {
    monitorExited = false;
    final InetSocketAddress remote = new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, port);
    KNXNetworkLink knxLink = null;
    ProcessCommunicator pc = null;
    
    try {
        knxLink = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(null, remote, false, TPSettings.TP1);
        pc = new ProcessCommunicatorImpl(knxLink);
        pc.addProcessListener(this);
        System.out.println("Monitoring network using net/IP server " + remoteHost + " ...");

        while (knxLink.isOpen()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        
        safeDetach(pc);
        safeClose(knxLink);
    } catch (final KNXException | InterruptedException | RuntimeException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in checking liveliness - " + e.getMessage());
        safeDetach(pc);
        safeClose(knxLink);
    }
    monitorExited = true;
}


private void safeDetach(ProcessCommunicator pc) {
    try {
        if (pc != null) pc.detach();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Could not safely detach pc - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void safeClose(KNXNetworkLink knxLink) {
    try {
        if (knxLink != null) knxLink.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Could not safely close link - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot avoid the while True, because the program runs in an endless while. If I cut the whole Executor & Runnable part before the while True, than the remoteHost and Port can only be changed on restarting the Program which is a very bad solution in my case. Is there any workaround?
Anyway: I will post an update in the next 5-6 hours whether this solved both problems ...
I especially like the methods safeDetach and safeClose! :D

Comment: if you need to keep your main thread alive - you can have while true() separately ... but the Runnable &  ScheduledExecutorService needs only be setup once and don't need to be in the loop

Comment: I cannot live with that solution :(
The problem with this solution is: it can happen that the remoteHost ip and port changes and the java program will not get restarted very often ...